# How to get this output from JSON in javascipt ny comparing student_id from mark_details and students_detail?

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object

JSON Object:

```
{
  "students_detail": [
    {
      "student_id": 1,
      "name": "abc",
      "roll_number": 10
    },
    {
      "student_id": 2,
      "name": "pqr",
      "roll_number": 12
    }
  ],
  "subject_details": [
    {
      "subject_id": 1,
      "subject_name": "math"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": 2,
      "subject_name": "english"
    }
  ],
  "exam_details": [
    {
      "exam_id": 1,
      "exam_name": "Prelim"
    }
  ],
  "mark_details": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "exam_id": 1,
      "subject_id": 1,
      "student_id": 1,
      "mark": 51
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "exam_id": 1,
      "subject_id": 2,
      "student_id": 2,
      "mark": 61
    }
  ]
}
```

Ouptut:

```
{
  "student_mark_details": [
    {
      "abc": {
          "roll_number": 10,
          "Prelim": [
            {
              "subject_name": "math",
              "mark": 51
            }
          ]
      },
      "pqr": {
          "roll_number": 12,
          "Prelim": [
           {
              "subject_name": "english",
              "mark": 61
            }
          ]
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

i tried using loops and accesing student_id in both object and comparing them but code gets too messy and complex,is there any way i can use map() or filter() in this or any other method.

i have no idea where to start,my brain is fried i know im asking lot but help will be appreciated (any link/source where i can learn this is fine too)

Comment: Are you trying to convert the data on top into the data structure on the bottom? Have you looked into [Json Deserialization?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deserializing-a-json-into-a-javascript-object/) I suspect converting the initial json data into a list of objects you could then manipulate them much easier into the structure you wanted and then [Serialize that back into json.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0):

Your output object really has a weird format: student_mark_details is an array of size 1 that contains an object that has all your students in it. Anyway, this should give you what you need. It is a format that you find often because it is a system with primary key and secondary key used a lot in databases.

The key to manage that is to start with what is at the core of what you are looking for (here, you want to describe students, so you should start from there), and then navigate the informations you need by using the primary/secondary keys. In JS, you can use the find() function in the case where one secondary key can be linked only to one primary key (ex: one mark is linked to one exam), and the filter() function when a secondary key can be linked to multiple secondary keys (ex: a student is linked to many grades).

I am not sure if this is 100% what you need because there are maybe some rules that are not shown in your example, but it solves the problem you submitted here. You might have to test it and change it depending of those rules. I don't know what your level is so I commented a lot

```
const data = {
  "students_detail": [
    {
      "student_id": 1,
      "name": "abc",
      "roll_number": 10
    },
    {
      "student_id": 2,
      "name": "pqr",
      "roll_number": 12
    }
  ],
  "subject_details": [
    {
      "subject_id": 1,
      "subject_name": "math"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": 2,
      "subject_name": "english"
    }
  ],
  "exam_details": [
    {
      "exam_id": 1,
      "exam_name": "Prelim"
    }
  ],
  "mark_details": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "exam_id": 1,
      "subject_id": 1,
      "student_id": 1,
      "mark": 51
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "exam_id": 1,
      "subject_id": 2,
      "student_id": 2,
      "mark": 61
    }
  ]
}

function format(data) {
  const output = {
    "student_mark_details": [{}]
  };

  //I start by looping over the students_detail because in the output we want a sumary by student
  data.students_detail.forEach(student => {
    //Initialization of an object for a particular student
    const individualStudentOutput = {}
    const studentId = student.student_id;
    const studentName = student.name;

    //The rollNumber is easy to get
    individualStudentOutput.roll_number = student.roll_number;

    //We then want to find the exams that are linked to our student. We do not have that link directly, but we know that our student is linked to some marks
    //Finds all the marks that correspond to the student
    const studentMarkDetails = data.mark_details.filter(mark => mark.id === studentId);

    studentMarkDetails.forEach(individualMark => {
      //Finds the exam that corresponds to our mark
      const examDetail = data.exam_details.find(exam => individualMark.exam_id === exam.exam_id);

      //Finds the subject that corresponds to our mark
      const subjectDetail = data.subject_details.find(subject => individualMark.subject_id === subject.subject_id);

      //We then create a grade that we will add to our exam
      const grade = {
        subject_name: subjectDetail.subject_name,
        mark: individualMark.mark
      }

      //We then want to add our grade to our exam, but we don't know if our output has already have an array to represent our exam
      //So in the case where it does not exist, we create one
      if (!individualStudentOutput[examDetail.exam_name]) {
        individualStudentOutput[examDetail.exam_name] = [];
      }

      //We then add our grade to the exam
      individualStudentOutput[examDetail.exam_name].push(grade);
    });

    //Now that we have finished our individual output for a student, we add it to our object
    output.student_mark_details[0][studentName] = individualStudentOutput;
  })

  return output;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(format(data)))
```